# Clutch Judder That Goes Away After Driving

Tags: clutch, manual-transmission, leak

If any of you have experience with this or know what could cause this please let me know I've taken it to two shops, one dealership and one was an indie shop.

Both of them charged me a diagnostic fee to tell me "clutch judder isn't unusual, the clutch still has plenty of life in it, there's nothing to do at this time."

I found something about clutch contamination while looking up the symptoms, and it seems like maybe this could be it. The explanation that clicked with me was if oil or condensation gets on the clutch it causes a slip-grab-slip pattern causing the judder, after the clutch heats up it burns whatever it is off and operates normally.

My car will violently judder during the first take off of the day, and every takeoff after until about 10 minutes into driving then stop completely and feel like a brand new car. It's crazy.

Im not interested in paying another diagnostic fee for someone to tell me not to worry about it. It's making the car a pain to drive.

Tips? Advice? Anything! Thank you for reading

2010 Honda Fit/Jazz | 85k Miles
| Manual Transmission

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 0):

Did these shops actually look at the clutch? Because this could be wear at 85k miles. Fluid contamination is also possible, and can be checked at the same time.

Annoying, but not a problem.

Comment: No, one shop only test drove it. The second shop test drove it and looked at the axels and mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the shop is full of it. And no oil won't burn off. 99% u need a new clutch and maybe flywheel. I wouldn't waste more time on it just replace it and move on with life.